# Use php vs Ajax for responsive UI

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

I am having a data of materials (14 Rows, 6 Columns) and putting in a HTML form of a website. I am designing with  with JavaScript as well as PHP.   Kindly intimate which one will be best (JavaScript or PHP) in terms of fast loading of pages?

Is there any better model for this one? I am providing the raw data in the tabular phone for better readability.

```
 SIZE  CLASS  THICK  PRESSURE  GRADE  PRICE
 100    K7    7.3     3.5       3.5   110.45
 100    K8    7.9     3.8       4.5   125.50
 100    K9    8.1     4.2       5.5   138.65 
 150    K7    7.7     3.7       3.6   121.50
 150    K8    8.3     4.3       4.6   141.00 
 150    K9    8.8     4.9       5.6   150.00 
 ...    ..    ...     ...       ...   ......
 ...    ..    ...     ...       ...   .....
 950    K9    13.3    7.9       7.9   850.00
```

if some one enters the Pipe dia & class in the HTML form, the Thickness, Pressure, grade & price is appearing. What I require is the speed and any other option apart from JS, PHP

Comment: __I am processing with JavaScript as well as PHP__? you are processing what?

Comment: if some one enters the Pipe dia & class in the HTML form, the Thickness, Pressure, grade & price is appearing. What I require is the speed and any other option apart from JS, PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you **two** possible solutions:

1. *Statically load your data using **php** and Use **javascript**.*
   As you mentioned you are having 14 Rows of data
   which is very small data, so you can statically load your data with php
   when the page loads for the first time. Then when the user enters
   say `Pipe dia` & `class` as *per your comment* you can use javascript (
   **jQuery** will be great for easier DOM manipulation) to show
   `Thickness`, `Pressure`, `grade` & `price` etc.

   **Advantage**: *very fast*

   **Disadvantage**: *As the data grows performance decreases, and loading your page for the first time will be very slow as you are having large data to load.*
2. *Use **Ajax** and **Php**.*
   If you think that your data could possibly grow large for the future, then loading large data could relatively
   inefficient. So if this is the case all you have to do is *load the
   needed row from backend on demand using ajax.*. I also suggest you
   use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for simplicity.

   **Advantage**:*Scalable, as your data grows performance will not decrease by significant amount.*

   **Disadvantage**:*As this sends a request to the server for every row it depends on the connection speed of your clients and is relatively difficult to implement in comparison to the above solution.*

*Personally I chose number 2 !*

Comment: Dear, could you simplify the Javascript with regard to jquery. I am furnishing the code (Javascript)

Comment: jQuery is just javascript library, you never used it?

Comment: Dear, I have added the java script code. Could you simply the code with jquery-Ajax?

Comment: You can reuse your javascript code, you only need to get the data row from the server side with ajax. I can give you the sample ajax code, but that will not help you. This is _basic_ knowledge you need to visit the link I post above and read it then try coding without copy pasting.

Comment: Please do help me, as I am poor in AJAX

Answer (score 0):

In general, JS is faster considerably than PHP. But js depends upon client side, it can crash the browser if client has low machine specifications, for example if you have thousands of records javascirpt has grater chances to crash the user browser due to insufficient hardware specs,

Comment: But  some of the browsers do n't accept JavaScript?

Comment: yeah so its beter to use php :)

Answer (score 0):

Today (2015), you can assume that every serious browser works fine with JavaScript. More important is the question if the IT Services of your company forbids JavaScript or reduces it to certain network segments. Then, if you implement a solution with JavaScript, you'll have to ask for permission.

With JavaScript, you can reach an extraordinary "feeling" of speed by quick and fluent reactions. While the user types pipe dia and class, the selection is immediately narrowed, step by step. You can't do this just by sending forms.

If you don't feel sure and you just send forms and get answers, it depends on the speed of your LAN. But honestly, if you do not transport hundreds of KB, you probably won't feel the refresh.